# Output is not expexted

Tags: scala

I want to know how the below code works and shows the output "hello hi"

```
  def greetSomeone(prefix:String) = (name:String) => println(prefix + " " + name)
  val helloSomeone = greetSomeone("Hello")
  helloSomeone("hi ")
```

Comment: What about it exactly do you need help with understanding? Do you understand that `greetSomeone` returns a function?

Comment: @Carcigenicate the output of above code is Hello hi. I want to know how the functions call is happening. function helloSomeone is not accepting any argument but still here we are passing one.  So exactly how above code works.

Comment: Again, note how the first function **returns a function**. It did in fact accept arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of Higher Order Function. See [docs.scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html)

`greetSomeone` is a method that returns a function with one argument.

With `helloSomeone("hi ")` you call this function.

You could also write `greetSomeone` with `currying` (see [docs.scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html)):

```
def greetSomeone(prefix:String)(name:String) = println(prefix + " " + name)
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks pme, it will be great if you can elaborate more.

Comment: I added the according reference.